# Can I use URL Content Type in a hangout app definition?

Tags: google-hangouts

In the xml which defines a hangout app I would like to use url content type as you can for a gadget:

e.g. `<Content type="url" href="http://www.google.com" />`

but when I do this the app fails to load.

I assume this is because the only supported content type is html.

Is this true and why would this be the case?

The reason I want to do this is that I would like to be able to edit the html with syntax highlighting. Embedding it in a cdata section of an xml doc makes this difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Hangouts only support type="html."

However, you can use our sample code for [Hangout IFramer](https://hangoutiframer.appspot.com/static/help.html) to iFrame from your servers.